# Is there a way to prevent Webpack showing all your un-minified files?

Tags: webpack, bundler, minify

I'm sure there's a way of doing this documented on the internet, but I think I'm lacking the correct terminology to find it.

Webpack currently minifies all my files, but then all my individual js files are still visible under `webpack://`. I've spotted this on a few actual (in production) websites too.

[image]

Is there a plugin or an option I can use to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make production build you should disable `source-map` by doing this:

```
devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : "source-map"
```

and enable this `production` env by setting flag during initiation of webpack:

```
NODE_ENV=production webpack
```

Comment: Oh that was easy. Weird that so many sites leave that on in production, no?